# Entity class mapping is invalid

Tags: php, symfony

Hi i am trying to create a OneToMany relationship between Page and Block tables but i am getting the following error on validating the schema:

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'mypath\Entity\Block' mapping is invalid:
* The association mypath\Entity\Block#pages refers to the inverse side field     mypath\Entity\Page#blocks which does not exist.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'mypath\Entity\Page' mapping is invalid:
* The association mypath\Entity\Page#block refers to the owning side field     mypath\Entity\Block#page which does not exist.
```

Following are my page and Block Entities

Page:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Block", mappedBy="page")
*/
private $block;
```

Block:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="block")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $pages;
```

I am not sure what wrong with it but seems to be something related to annotations. Please help, Thanks !!!

Comment: Personally, I'd name the ManyToOne side singular, so $page (because there's only one page for a given block), but whatever works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution. The problem was with the names.

So if we read it in normal terms, it make sense.

A page can have many blocks. So page entity will be

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Block", mappedBy="pages")
 */
private $blocks;
```

Similarly, a block belongs to many pages. So block entity will be

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="blocks")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $pages;
```

targetEntity will always be the class name which would be singular and field names will be plural(in case of OneToMany and may be in other cases as well).

That resolves the issue. Have a good day !!!

Comment: Actually, this is not really doing what you think it is.  You need to use a ManyToMany relation between block and page. As it is, a block can only belong to one page.

Answer (score 0):

In the annotation, you call the properties "blocks and "page", but they're called "block" and "pages" in the actual code.

Page:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Block", mappedBy="page")
*/
private $blocks;
```

Block:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="blocks")
*/
private $page;
```

Comment: I tried that but its not working as well. Also i edited the post added JoinColumn which i was missing but still getting the error.

Comment: I assume the intent is for the page to contain many blocks? What's the field name of the foreign key to the page in the blocks table?

Comment: Yes the intent is that pages can have many blocks. The field name in the blocks table is page_id that is automatically generated by symfony. I did not mention it in block entity.